# Can I create equidistant hull meshes (3D level sets) in Blender?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

given is:

- a very complicated mesh object, with potentially a large amount of inner detail.
- a positive value (a parameter) called alpha

I want a watertight mesh that is defined as the following:
"every point on the mesh is exactly alpha meters away(minimum distance) from the original mesh".

I would want this for alpha values higher than 2 meters. Solidify modifier doesnt work as advertised in this setting (when alpha gets high), and skin modifier just crashes Blender.

Also would love to hear an established name for such a mesh.

approximations that work on the convex hull would be ok as well.

Comment: You can use a *Displace* modifier, but like *Solidify* it wont account for inner geometry

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, thanks. It looks great when I modify the strength and midlevel paramaters. I would like a single parameter (denoted alpha in the question) that governs the margin inbetween original surface, and new displaced surface (in the normal direction). Say that I want 0.5 meters, 1 meters and 1.5 meteres... what should midlevel and strength be set to?

Comment: Always set the mid level to zero, then control only from *Strength*